# I used to be able to launch Battlefield 4 Singleplayer/Multiplayer without Battlelog. What happened?

Tags: battlefield-4

I haven't played BF4 for a few weeks now, and I finally decided to start the game up again, but when I started it up, it sent me to the Battlelog website. This has never happened before, please help. I have Battlefield 4 Premium, btw.

Comment: Verify the gamefiles through Origin, I booted-up BF4 earlier today and I don't have the same issue. So I think something is wrong on your end.

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though others have had a similar issue. This [link](https://answers.ea.com/t5/Battlefield-4/Origin-still-launches-Battlelog-instead-of-the-new-UI/td-p/6008787) will bring you to the Origin forum pages where it was discussed.

Some of the recommendations included:

- Check that you have the most up to date version of Origin installed.
- Clearing the Origin cache files and then restarting the game.
- Try uninstalling and reinstalling battlefield.
- Uninstall both battlefield and origin and then reinstall both. (Try others first)